# Rotation of an elongated geostationary satellite

Tags: artificial-satellite

I read somewhere that if you place an elongated geostationary satellite tangential to the Earth it will rotate so that its long axis is in line with the radius. Presumably, as soon as one end goes slightly inside of the tangent it is fractionally heavier and the opposite end lighter which then is reinforced.  what is this called/where can I find out more?

Comment: gravity gradient

Comment: There are a number of interesting questions regarding gravity gradient stabilization on the site that you might like to read. Here's one with a lot of detail https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51671/6944

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tidal or [gravity gradient stabilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity-gradient_stabilization),  and works due to the point closer to earth having slightly more attractive force due the inverse square law so will tend towards vertical given time. The effect is not [restricted to geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Duration_Exposure_Facility).